# Aborting XMLHttpRequest In Android Webview

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, android-webview

I have Android App that contains a Webview (Android API 25).

In that Webview i am trying to open a webpage that does a network speed test.

To implement the speed test i am trying to download a file from my server using XMLHttpRequest (GET method).

After 10 seconds i am trying to stop the download by calling XMLHttpRequest.abort().

The abort of the request causes "net:ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES" exception from Android's Webview.

How can i stop the download without causing the exception ?